# Python keyboard.add_hotkey(): как правильно сохранить значения горячих клавиш?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binding, клавиатура

В одном из приложений на библиотеке [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/), пытаюсь реализовать установку и последующее сохранение горячей(-их) клавиш(-и), для того чтобы после перезапуска приложения, кнопки подгружались, устанавливались и их не надо было заново биндить.

**Документация:** [ссылка на документацию по библиотеке keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Храню кнопки в БД, использую `SQLite`

**Алгоритм такой:**

1. Если в базе пусто, создаем значение `button` и вызываем функцию для прослушивания клавиш.
2. С помощью вызванной функции биндим  клавишу или сочетание клавиш
3. Алгоритм определяет одна ли это клавиша, или несколько и добавляет в `keyboard.add_hotkey()`, после чего сохраняет.
4. Если при входе в базе не пусто - достает значение и также устанавливает `keyboard.add_hotkey()`.

**Проблема:**

Все работает, но есть одно НО. Значение нажатой клавиши определяется текущей раскладкой. Если сохранить клавишу/сочетание клавиш на русском языке, то потом, когда я снова запущу приложение с включенной английской раскладкой, `keyboard` выдаст ошибку о том, что не знает, например, клавиши *"Ч"*. Точно также при переходе с английской раскладки на русскую.

- Если сохранять кнопки через `keyboard.hook()`, то из переданного события можно получить как название кнопки - *"K"/"Л"*, так и ее код - 37. И если биндить уже код, тогда проблемы не возникает, ведь код кнопки общий для обеих раскладок. Но мне нужна возможность биндить 2 клавиши, а `keyboard.hook()` сразу отправляет `event` при нажатии одной.
- Я пробовал получать коды кнопок через `keyboard.key_to_scan_codes()`, но в таком случае их нельзя забиндить через метод `keyboard.add_hotkey()`, так как он принимает значение `key` либо в виде строки: `'ALT+F'`, либо в виде числа. И если я захочу записать комбинацию клавиш в виде `int` - я получу сумму этих чисел, то есть совсем другую ОДНУ клавишу.

*Примеры:*

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift', callback) ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅ True
keyboard.add_hotkey(29, callback) ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅ True (29 - код кнопки CTRL)
keyboard.add_hotkey(16+17, callback) ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅ True (16 - Q, 17 - W, но в результате получаем 33 - кнопка F)
keyboard.add_hotkey('16+17', callback) ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅ False (16 - Q, 17 - W, но keyboard говорит что это неизвестные клавиши)
```

---

**Код:** *(не уверен, что он нужен)*

```
import keyboard, sqlite3

def callback():
    print('Функция вызвана')

def bind_keys():
    print('Нажмите клавишу / Сочетание двух клавиш')

    key = keyboard.read_hotkey(suppress=False)
    key = str(key).split('+')

    if len(key) == 2:
        print(f'Нажато две кнопки: {key[0].upper()}, {key[1].upper()}')
        key = f'{key[0]}+{key[1]}'
    elif len(key) == 1:
        print(f'Нажата одна кнопка: {key[0].upper()}')
        key = key[0]

    keyboard.add_hotkey(key, callback, suppress = False)
    
    sql.execute(f"SELECT button FROM test WHERE button = '{key}'")
    if sql.fetchone() is None:
        sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO test VALUES('{key}')")
        db.commit()
        print('Клавиши сохранены')
    keyboard.wait()


db = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(button TEXT)")
db.commit()

sql.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
key = sql.fetchone()
if key != None:
    keyboard.add_hotkey(key[0], callback, suppress = False)
    keyboard.wait()
else:
    bind_keys()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое логичное - сохранить названия клавиш в словарь типа

```
keys = {
   'w' : 'ц',
   'a' : 'ф',
   's' : 'ы',
   'd' : 'в'
}
```

И затем, проверяя текущую раскладку, например так

```
import ctypes
      
def get_layout():
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419':
        return 'ru'
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4090409':
        return 'en'
```

Устанавливать сочетания клавиш уже по значениям словаря:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey(f"{keys['ctrl']}+{keys['shift']}", callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

В документации это не отражено, но в [исходниках](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py#L706) `add_hotkey` видно, что метод принимает список, то есть можно просто передать ему список сканкодов.

Любопытно то, что при передаче строки вида 'ALT+F' она всё равно превращается в сканкоды. Учитывать разные раскладки при создании горячих клавиш не нужно.

Comment: На самом деле, около года назад снова столкнулся с этой проблемой и также залез в исходники. Решение действительно проще, чем кажется :)